# Angular localize unable to run CLI

Tags: angular, localization

I am trying to implement localize into my freshly build angular application.

my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.0.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.5.12",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^9.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.2.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "10.0.6",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^14.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.x",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.26",
    "mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2": "^1.0.42",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.9",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "next-session": "^3.2.3",
    "ng-uikit-pro-standard": "file:ng-uikit-pro-standard-9.3.1.tgz",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "screenfull": "3.3.x",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
```

```
npx ng xi18n

ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(49,25): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Expression form not supported in 'reducers'
    'reducers' contains the error at src/app/store/index.ts(29,3).
```

the line 29 is:

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<NoahState> = {
  [fromUnits.featureKey]: fromUnits.reducer,
  [fromUnit.featureKey]: fromUnit.reducer,
...
}
```

so as I understand the dynamic naming expression is not supported for some reason, is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "dynamic naming expression"?

Comment: @k.vincent I mean this: [fromUnits.featureKey]: fromUnits.reducer,